# Map virtual drive from a folder with custom icon and limited storage size C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, virtual-disk

I have a weird requirement.

I have to map a folder as a `Virtual Drive` in `My Computer` with a custom drive icon on it. Also the mapped virtual drive should be of predefined limited size (say XX GB).

I know and mapped a folder as a virtual drive in my computer but I am not able to limit the size of the drive as it is a kind of `Shortcut` to the folder and also we can not limit a folder to a specific size.
While searching on the topic, I came across `IsolatedStorage` which is not what I needed. I also found `DefineDosDevice(int flags, string devname, string path)` in `kernel32.dll` through which I am able to map a folder to my computer but not able to achieve other functionality.

Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/mount-vhd-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it is possible.  Do you think you could create an application that registers these folders and then add it to a file system watcher.  Intercept any writes and cancel them if the file size + the current folder size is greater than the max.

Maybe break the problem down into small chunks.

I'm sure there is a better way, but a service application that integrates itself with the OS would be a very good option.

Hope that helps.  Please dont minus rep, I just like problems like this.  Its a very good question!

Comment: But what about the size that will be displayed in `My Computer` for that disk?